# Can yolov7 detect very tiny objects from thermal images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5

I was using yolov5 to detect animals on the sea surface.
[image: yolov5 detected image]
but yolo had a difficult time doing it because the waves were also similar in shape and color to the birds (lots of false positives). And when the drone flew really high or when non whitish birds were involved, it didn't detect them at all. They were tiny and not really distinct to the eye. ***Will this issue be resolved if I use a thermal camera?*** I hope the thermal sensors can distinguish the cold sea and the warm animals like this,
[image: image from google]
and yolo can easily detect them even if they were tiny. Is my assumption valid? Can **yolov7** be used to train and detect the thermal imagery of tiny birds?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. -- stock photos are not indicative of real-world results. your question requires actually trying what you suggest, so you should go and do that. this isn't a programming question.

Comment: i wanted to buy a thermal camers when i was confident getting one would actually give me results.

Comment: you can surely borrow a camera from someone. make sure it's actually seeing thermal emissions from those flying creatures. they're feathered. that could be good thermal insulation, meaning the thermal picture *might* not show much either. some googling makes me optimistic though.